# Search for last value in specific column

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am using Excel Interop in C# to read from a Excel Sheet.
My Excel Sheet has always the same Structure:

```
   | A    | B    | C    | D    |
1  |      |      |      |      |
2  | Text | Text | Text | Text |
3  |      |      |      |      |
4  | Text | Text | Text | Text |
5  | Text | Text | Text | Text |
6  | Text | Text | Text | Text |
...| ...  | ...  | ...  | ...  |
75 | Text | Text | Text | Text |
76 |      |      |      |      |
77 | Text |      |      |      |    
78 | Text |      |      |      |    
79 | Text |      |      |      |
```

What i now want to get, is that start and end row of my required data. In the example above it would be "4" for the start row and "75" for the end row.

The start row is no problem: i get it using `Range.Find("text").Row` because i know the first entry of my data.

The problem is getting line 75, because the function `.End` always gives me the very last cell of the sheet. This would be 79 in my example.

I could loop form row 4 to 76 and check if cell is empty but this does not seem to be very smart and efficient.

Is it possible to ask for example for the last not empty cell in column D? This would solve my problem.

Hope this was not too confusing...

Best Regards and thanks in advance,

Julian

Comment: btw where you load your excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to ask for example for the last not empty cell in column D? This would solve my problem."

Maybe this solution will be good for you. It finds first blank element, but I think you could edit it:
[first blank row in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752971/first-blank-row-in-excel)